# Withdrawal of MPF after 60-years old

Tags: retirement, hong-kong, malaysia

I am a Malaysian, I worked in Hong Kong Interbank Clearing Ltd (HKICL) from Nov 2001 till Dec 2004. I resigned from HKICL and left Hong Kong in Dec 2004.
My question: I am 60 year old now (my birth date: 1 June 1954), am i entitled to claim any remaining [MPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Provident_Fund_%28Hong_Kong%29) now? if yes, how do I proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the people at MPFA; their [FAQ](http://www.mpfa.org.hk/eng/information_centre/faq/employee/mpf_employee/index.jsp) does not address your situation directly, but one answer suggests that you could have claimed your accrued benefits when you left, maybe you can use the same procedure now.

You probably can claim them now just as if you were still living in Hong Kong, but note that regular retirement is only at age 65, though you can declare an early retirement starting at age 60; I'm not sure whether that reduces your benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

According to "[Early Withdrawal of Benefits - MPFA](http://www.mpfa.org.hk/eng/main/employee/early_withdrawal_of_benefits.jsp)", you can claim your MPF earlier than the age of 65 with one of the following reasons:

1. Early retirement (60 years old or above)
2. Permanent departure from Hong Kong (can only be used **once** in a lifetime)
3. Total incapacity
4. Small balance account
5. Death

Seems the first two options might fit your scenario.

To get your money back, you need to [fill in some forms](http://www.mpfa.org.hk/eng/information_centre/forms/mpf_schemes/scheme_members/payment_of_accrued_benefits/) and make declarations. The administrative procedures might be different for different trustees, so you might want to [call your trustee(s)](http://www.mpfa.org.hk/eng/main/useful_links/approved_trustees/) first.